# _com_error::ErrorMessage will cause memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, ado

I try to use VC++ & ADO to connect to SQL Server. And use C++ Memory Validator to check if there are any memory leaks. Below are my codes:

```
    ADODB::_ConnectionPtr  Conn1;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Trap any error/exception.
    try
    {
        // Create and Open Connection Object.
        Conn1.CreateInstance( __uuidof( ADODB::Connection) );
        Conn1->ConnectionString = _bstr_t(L"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MYPC;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        Conn1->Open( _bstr_t(L""), _bstr_t(L""), _bstr_t(L""), -1 );
        Conn1->Execute(_bstr_t(_T("DROP TABLE UnexistingTable;")), NULL, ADODB::adCmdText | ADODB::adExecuteNoRecords);
        Conn1->Close();
    }
    catch(_com_error& e) 
    {
        CString strError = e.ErrorMessage();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
```

The C++ Memory Validator will report the following memory leak, which is caused by _com_error::ErrorMessage():

[image: memory leak reported by C++ Memory Validator]

But I check the document on ErrorMessage, and it said:

The string returned is allocated by the FormatMessage API, and it is released when the _com_error object is destroyed.

So it seems there are nothing wrong with my codes. I try to put a breakpoint in _com_error::~_com_error destructor, but VS said it cannot put breakpoint there due to the code optimization. So I cannot know whether the message is released successfully or not.

Comment: Usually to debug properly, compile with `-o0 -g` . Use valgrind to check for memory leak.

Comment: You could try to catch the exception as a const reference instead: `catch(const _com_error& e)`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Hi, I try to add the const modifier but that procduces the same result. Still memory leak.

Comment: @Clonk, Sorry but valgrind seems to not work on WIndows?

Comment: @Clonk, Currently I am using Debug settings, I check the compiler/link options. It uses -od (disable optimizaton). I cannot find -g option, what is the meaning of this?

Comment: @alancc Good. Perhaps it's a false positive from C++ Memory Validator?

Comment: @alacc I assumed you were on Linux. -`g` option is debugging symbol.

Comment: @Clonk, I am under Windows and using Visual Studio 2008. Thanks.